# Why does air circulate on an airfoil --- The Kutta Condition

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, forces, aerodynamics

[image]

Why does the air circulate on a flowing airfoil, thus giving rise to increased velocity (circulation + relative airspeed) above the wing and hence decreased pressure.

Comment: Increased velocity does not necessarily require decreased pressure.  That rule applies inside a tube, but not in open atmosphere.  There are some good treatises on airfoil forces. Did you even look at the http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13030/ links which popped up as you asked this question?

Comment: The reason for the circulation is viscosity. Thin boundary layers around the surface of the airfoil cause the air to leave the trailing edge smoothly at low angles of attack.

Comment: [*Where you got that picture*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-Kutta) is a better explanation than I could ever give.