# Equal transit time fallacy and Newton's laws of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I've seen the equal transit time theory being used to explain aerodynamic lift [basis is Bernoulli's principle] several times. However recently I've been told that there is **NO** physical compulsion for air above an aerofoil to have to travel across it at the same time as the air below the aerofoil.

There're quite a few questions on this site that deal with the fallacy but none [as far as I've seen] specifically mention ***WHAT PROBLEMS WOULD ONE ENCOUNTER BY ACCEPTING THE EQUAL TRANSIT THEORY.***

I mean sure, plenty of sources bring up the concept of air parcels having been proved [by computer simulation] to travel FASTER above the aerofoil than below it, but I haven't come across any *specific* contradiction the equal transit theory would throw up.

Though I vaguely recall coming across some article that stated the equal transit time *would violate Newton's laws of motion*. If this is correct then ***WHICH law of motion would it violate*** and ***HOW would the law be violated***?

If there's anything else [apart from the laws of motion] which contradict the equal transit theory, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Equal transit time is the worst explanation for lift ever... Sorry you had to encounter it!

Comment: Any explanation of lift that is _not_ based on momentum conservation is simply false. That includes a naive use of Bernoulli which pretends that there is such a thing as "suction above the wing" while completely ignoring the really essential part of the flow under and behind the wing.

Comment: ^ I don't think Bernoulli's theorem disavows momentum conservation, though it doesn't specifically dwell on it.....also how does it "pretend" there's suction above the wing? As for flow BEHIND the wing, I've never really put much though into it, but I guess it does deserve some attention, thanks for pointing that out............ @CuriousOne

Comment: Bernoulli's Principle is an expression of energy conservation. Energy is not conserved in this case, to begin with and energy and momentum conservation are two completely different laws based on different spacetime symmetries. If you never put any thought into what happens behind the wing, then you never understood where lift comes from, I am afraid, and neither have the innumerable textbook authors who have been applying Bernoulli wrong for a century.

Comment: ^ Bernoulli's Principle DOES seem like a feasible explanation to aerodynamic lift, also I don't really see why energy shouldn't be conserved in this case. As for energy and momentum conservation, aren't they complementary [I've got serious doubts if we could say they're COMPLETELY different]? As for "different space-time symmetries" I haven't studied physics from that perspective yet [I'm 17 years old], so it would be helpful if you could explain it somehow.....differently? @CuriousOne

Comment: Energy is not conserved because planes fall out of the sky without an engine... it's called drag and it is a non-conservative force. No drag - no lift. See Noether's theorem for the difference between energy and momentum conservation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem. In any case, if you are having trouble visualizing momentum conservation with fixed wing aircraft, look at the derivation of power requirements for rotary-wing aircraft with disk loading (and there Bernoulli is actually applicable): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_loading

Comment: @AaronAbraham To head off the next possible question about "How can lift be generated in an inviscid fluid without violating conservation of energy," check out my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46131/does-a-wing-in-a-potential-flow-have-lift/46134#46134). Always remember -- any "model" for lift (Bernoulli, equal transit, bound vortex, etc etc) is a simplification for making the mathematics easier. They all neglect something, or many things, and they only stick around because they "work" within the limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal transit time would violate Newton's laws of motion in the sense that the computer simulations that are based on Newton's laws of motion show that equal transit time is false.  I don't think you can show that using a simple heuristic argument or a simple equation, but the computer simulations do count as a valid proof, albeit perhaps not one you find satisfying.  (Provided, of course, you've been careful to show that the error bars are small enough to rule out the possibility of equal transit time.)

In fact, I don't think that equal transit time does violate any of Newton's laws of motion *in general*, because if you make the airplane wing perfectly up-down symmetric then presumably it would be true.  So it isn't physically impossible in general, it just happens to not be true in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Yes, but I'm really curious to know WHICH law of motion is violated and HOW. Thank you all the same though.......

Comment: @AaronAbraham I don't think there's a simple analytic answer to that.

Comment: ^ Ouch.......thanks anyway though....

Comment: @AaronAbraham I expanded on my answer

Comment: "if you make the airplane wing perfectly up-down symmetric then presumably it would be true"- not so. Again - lift doesn't occur without circulation, and circulation is nothing more than top air getting to the trailing edge before bottom air.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - I never claimed that you'd get any lift from a symmetric wing, just that equal-transit time would be true.

Comment: @tparker: Sure. You get equal transit time if and only if lift is zero (regardless of airfoil shape).

Answer (score 4):

As always, read John Denker's wonderful [*ebook*](https://www.av8n.com/how/).

To quickly answer the question, the equal-time argument is a wrong application of Bernoulli.
Bernoulli is right. Bernoulli plus the Kutta condition (air can't flow up over the trailing edge) is what makes flight possible.

If one accepted the equal-time argument

- it would not explain how airplanes can fly inverted, or use symmetrical airfoils, as aerobatic aircraft do.
- it would result in zero circulation, resulting in zero lift. Read Denker about this.

Comment: Although I was hoping for something more directly related to any of the laws of motion, I guess this would suffice......Thank you....

Comment: @AaronAbraham: Bernoulli is nothing more than $F=ma$ (conservation of momentum) in a fluid. If there is lift, then there is higher pressure below and lower pressure above. Therefore airspeed is lower below and higher above, so the air above gets to the trailing edge *first* (even if the path above is longer). To a first approximation, the shape doesn't matter, as long as the trailing edge is sharp (so the air can't flow around to the top). The shape affects things like stall speed, drag, etc. If the air on top doesn't get to the back edge first - no circulation, no downwash, no lift.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty great book.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Darn.....I didn't think there would be a [pretty direct] answer to why air would flow faster above the aerofoil, but 'continuity of flow' didn't really hit me earlier....THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Equal transit time theory (ETTT) violates Newton's third law.  ETTT claims that upward force is generated without an equal and opposite downward reaction.   The typical diagram that accompanies equal transit shows airflow lines behind the wing that are undisturbed.  Nice tranquil straight lines.  The story has been told about the air speeding up over the top so that air molecule pairs get reunited at the trailing edge, leading to a mistatement of Bernoulli's principle and a claim this acceleration produces lift.  Downwash is no part of the story.   If the wing is lifted without massive downwash, that violates Newton's third.