# How does this help an aeroplane to fly?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I read it somewhere on the internet that wings of an aeroplane are designed in such a way, that they increase the velocity of air above the wings and so pressure above the plane becomes less than the pressure below it and therefore the aeroplane flies well in air, but how is velocity increased above the wings of an aeroplane?

Comment: The increased velocity refers to the 'Bernoulli explanation' of lift which is not (significantly) contributing to making the airplane fly. For the true answers, check out [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290) and the answers to it

Comment: I am new here and so i have not seen the question be4

Comment: @Michiel The 'Bernoulli explanation' does explain how faster air reduces the static pressure above the wing compared to below. The resulting pressure differential over the area of the wing generates lift. What the 'Bernoulli explanation' does not explain is **why** the air is flowing faster over the top of the wing. I discuss more of this issue in my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/63080/21144).

Comment: Here is a little bit more info from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Misunderstandings_about_the_generation_of_lift).

Comment: Here is another related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51503/21144