# The torque produced in the rotor blades of an axial flow turbine

Tags: torque, aerodynamics

I want to ask about the torque experienced by a axial flow turbine, and how the torque is related to the ange of attack, or pitch angle of the turbine blades.

(I'm new to technical terms, please bear with me)

Comment: This question *may* be better suited to Engineering SE. There is definitely physics here, so I'd say it's your choice, but a physicist will likely only be able to give a very rough, not very quantitative description grounded on momentum transfer. Accurate models of this kind of thing are to be found in engineering design specifications and the like, as there are all kinds of "fudge factors" added here and there to model effects whose models are intractable either analytically or often even numerically.

Comment: Okay, can you suggest any keywords that can guide me in my search, I'll ask engineering section too.

Comment: I'm not to up with the Engineering SE it's fairly new. I'd be looking at fluid dynamics, turbine etc. Also have a look at the Physics SE question ["What Really Allows Airplanes to Fly"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/26076) - there's quite a good deal of discussion of angle of attack in the answers there.