# Fluid Dynamics applied to Aircraft wings

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aircraft

On aircraft wings, the bottom is flat and the top is curved. I know this benefits the aircraft by producing lift, but I wish to understand how. I'm told it has something to do with how fluids behave.

Comment: Very closely related to [What really allows airplanes to fly?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/), which answers your question and more.

Comment: Also you might get **two** different reasons in textbooks as to how the lift is created, thinking about which one is right may teach you a lot about physics. It did for me anyways, best of luck with it.

Comment: Please check out the other answers on the site. The flat-bottom-curved-top business is a widely-taught absolutely wrong explanation, and totally fails to explain aerobatic airplanes, which have symmetric airfoils. They fly just as well upside-down as right-side up. Almost any shape can fly, as long as it pulls the air into a downwash.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.