# How a paper plane(rocket) flies in air? what is science behind it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, aerodynamics

What factors helps a paper plane to fly and can you explain how these factors help the plane to fly?

Comment: Hi Jayanth Reddy Avula and welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. See [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Should any check my work questions be made on topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) posts on meta for more information.

Comment: Have a look through [the results of this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=paper+plane)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What really allows airplanes to fly?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/)

Comment: You don't realize it as you walk around or maybe run, but if you're in a car at high speed and you put your hand in the wind, ***air is heavy stuff***. I encourage you to learn about how things fly in it, and [*here's an excellent place to start.*](http://www.av8n.com/)

Answer (score 0):

One commonly overlooked factor is how it is thrown. Modern air planes carry their own power while paper airplanes are typically thrown by hand. If it is thrown very quickly then the air flow likely to be turbulent. If thrown slowly we can model the air flow as laminar and predict its flight path more accurately.

Comment: Got any sources of studies for this claim (turbulent vs laminar flows as a function of throwing velocity)?

Comment: I really don't like to downvote, but I would encourage you to learn something about the subject. Aviation and rocketry have been around for a century, so there is a lot you can learn from those who know.