# What is a simple, effective, and physically consistent explanation of Bernoulli's principle (in the context of airfoil lift)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation, lift, steady-state

I am not here to continue any debate about [what really allows airplanes to fly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-really-allows-airplanes-to-fly). Rather, what I am looking for is an informed, thoughtful, illuminating and self-contained explanation of Bernoulli's principle in the context of airfoil lift.

Assume that the reader has an undergraduate/graduate background in physics/math/fluid dynamics e.g. has a basic understanding of boundary layer theory, control volume analysis/derivation in continuity and momentum equations, and can understand the difference between Eulerian vs. Lagrangian specifications when prompted (I suspect that these are all be relevant to Bernoulli's principle...?) but please avoid particularly esoteric results; keep concise-ness and elegance in mind for clarity's sake.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to PSE. There are lots of duplicates on this question, I think you will need to piece them together, to achieve the standard you set :) my point really is that the answers are not written to order (no offence meant), but rather for a range of levels of knowledge

Comment: @Countto10 will this post be marked as duplicate? I can't claim to have exhaustively searched but there seems not to be a canonical reference explaining this.

Comment: I use Google and the terms you want to see and then Physics Stack Exchange, rather than the site search engine itself. Best of luck with it,  duplicates depend on whether users feels the points you raise have been covered, they may well  not have been.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What really allows airplanes to fly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/)

Comment: You are asking about the [*Coanda effect*](https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/spins.html#sec-coanda), which is not the same as what makes wings work.