# Does bernoulli's principle exert a downward pull on a moving ship?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

If you hold a spoon with its convex side next to a column of running tap water, it will be drawn to it, but does this apply to moving ships, where the hull is rounded like the spoon, and the water is moving under it is sped up due to the curvature, therefore decreasing pressure and pulling the ship downwards?

Comment: Your question might be as tricky as asking why airplanes fly https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-really-allows-airplanes-to-fly/77735#77735

Comment: The force you consider here should be negligible compared with the buoyancy, and the dragging force of the water.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planing_(boat) says hydrodynamic lift acts to lift a boat, not pull it downwards.

Comment: I was referring to ships that float from hydrostatic lift where their hulls are typically rounded, unlike planing boats where the hull is desgined more flat. I think ytlu answered it for me, but thank you too.