# Newtons third law explained on an airfoil at a molecular level

Tags: aerodynamics

I understand there are many different ways to explain lift on an airfoil, one of which is flow turning, that being due to the coanda effect on the upper surface of the airfoil, it deflects incoming air downwards, resulting in an equal and opposite reaction.

I can understand this on the lower side to a somewhat extent if there is a preexisting angle of attack, but otherwise, i could only see relative pressure on the wing from flow turning acting straight down on the upper surface.

Here is a very crude visual example of my thought process, It's not the prettiest but I hope that someone can understand it and clear up my confusion. I can understand how the rocket produces such thrust, but not a wing.

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/305718

Comment: @ACB Unfortunately not, I dont understand how newtons third law works with the airfoil at a mollecular level, I can see with the rocket, air particles push against the combustion chamber and nozzle but cannot push the other way apart from some spots in the combustion chamber at the bottom, This is intuitive, On the other hand with the wing, I do not understand how turning the air on top downwards can result in such a force at a mollecular level

Comment: Maybe you will find better explanations [on a different site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16193/how-do-wings-generate-lift/16202#16202).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an illustration that might help. The air both on top and bottom turns downward https://youtu.be/aFO4PBolwFg